# how to create a table by fixing this syntax error in mysql?

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I've edit this as you told me and i got a new error now..

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS visitors ( id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
country varchar(500) NOT NULL, coffee int(11), tea int(11), mate int(11), 
cocoa int(11) 
)ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

SQL query:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS visitors ( id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
country varchar(500) NOT NULL, coffee int(11), tea int(11), mate int(11),
cocoa int(11)
)ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: 1) Excess bracket at the end of DDL (before semicolon). 2) No parenthesis in `PRIMARY KEY (id)`.

Comment: You have already created the table. The error is in your INSERT statement. Read the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated query,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS visitors ( id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
country varchar(500) NOT NULL, coffee int(11), tea int(11), mate int(11), 
cocoa int(11), PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1
```

One excessive bracket was at the end and `PRIMARY KEY id` is missing brackets around `(id)`

Comment: thanks but i've edit this as you told me but i got a new error(my post it has been updated with the new error)

Comment: Remove id as id is auto_increment in your case, ```INSERT INTO visitors (country,coffee,tea,mate, cocoa) VALUES ('Algeria','79','5','0','1')```